# How to add image in 'fullcalendar' header section?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to display some text as well as an image next to it in fullcalendar header section.

I have a full calendar that displays names as the header and relative data in the columns below based on the date. I want to display name as well as a picture next to it. I tried appending html elements for test purpose and didn't get the expected result.

This is the section where header is assigned with a value

```
$.map(SomeJSON, function (resourceitem, i) {
    var resource = new Object();
    resource.id = resourceitem.UserID.toString();
    resource.title = resourceitem.UserName;
    if (resourceitem.UserID == scheduleitem.AssignedStaff) {
        $('div[id*=calendarAgendaSchedule]').fullCalendar('addResource', 
        resource, scroll);
        }                       
    });
```

[This is the output before appending additional html element to title.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcEP.png)

I tried appending html tag to the title.

```
$.map(SomeJSON, function (resourceitem, i) {
    var resource = new Object();
    resource.id = resourceitem.UserID.toString();
    resource.title = resourceitem.UserName+'<div class="text-accent">test</div> ';
    if (resourceitem.UserID == scheduleitem.AssignedStaff) {
        $('div[id*=calendarAgendaSchedule]').fullCalendar('addResource', 
        resource, scroll);
        }                       
    });
```

[This is the output after appending additional html element to title.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To6IC.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMzAD.png)

Comment: you're asking for header pictures per resource?

Comment: Yes. I want to add an image next to the names in the header.

Comment: Check the image in the question.

Comment: This doesn't work because the title property is treated as text by fullCalendar, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need [resourceRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceRender). Try the code bellow. Its a working code to show images on the left side of each resource but you can tweek some css to achieve what you expect.

```
  resourceRender: function(res){
    let imageStyles= "background:url('../assets/media/users/100_4.jpg') left center no-repeat;\
        border-radius:50%;\
        width: 30px;\
        height: 30px;\
        background-size: 35px;\
        margin-right:10px;\
        display: inline-block;"
    let elStyles = "display: flex;\
        justify-content: center;\
        align-items: center;"
    res.el.innerHTML = '<div style="'+elStyles+'">\
                      <div style="'+imageStyles+'">\
                      </div><div>'+res.resource.title+'</div>\
                    </div>';

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the [resourceRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/resourceRender) function to modify the elements.

```
   resourceRender: function(resourceObj,labelTds, bodyTds) {
      labelTds.append('<img src="<your img url>">'); //using jquery to append the image tag to the element
    },
```

P.S. The resourceObj will hold all your resource information. you can add a new value to your resource objects holding the image url and then use this inside teh resourceRender function.